# OpenSSL BIO: single SSL_write broken in two SSL records with TLS 1.0 only

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, tcp, openssl

I wanna send this message **"Hello world! \n Bye world!"** using following code. This code send the message in 2 SSL record but I need to send it in 1 SSL record.

I read something about base64 [here](http://doctrina.org/Base64-With-OpenSSL-C-API.html) and [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BIO_f_base64.html) but I don't how to use them in my code! Can any one help me to solve my problem.

**Problem:** I want to send message in one part not 2 part that separated by "\n"!

**More Description:** I use OpenSSL s_client to connect it, I forced it to use TLSv1 and sniff networks using wireshark. Actually this code is simplified of a bigger project for being Database Proxy. In main project we need send a message to a server that is not under our control and it can only process 1 SSL record.

**My OpenSSL Command:**

```
s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:9999 -tls1
```

**Wireshark Result for Message:**

```
17 03 01 00 24 db f3 59 37 98 78 3b b6 06 b0 c1 66 0c 78 04 4d 50 60 54 19 37 fe 
77 65 27 7f 4e e8 4e 9a d7 94 66 3f 0d 03 17 03 01 00 34 83 a8 39 b3 3e 9a 35 7b 
a2 64 07 35 9b c5 d7 d0 c9 03 3c 43 ac d8 1c ad d5 0f 55 34 10 6c 99 3e 57 b1 51 
d4 a5 36 6a 8e 23 08 e0 2d 33 c1 53 63 4e d2 bd bd
```

**My Simulation Code:**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

static void ssl_set_sys_error(int ssl_error)
{
    int error = 0;

    switch (ssl_error) {
    case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
        error = 0;
        break;
    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
#ifdef SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT
    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT:
#endif
#ifdef SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT
    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT:
#endif
        error = 1;
        break;
    case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
        /* Protocol error. */
#ifdef EPROTO
        error = EPROTO;
#else
        error = SOCKET_ECONNRESET;
#endif
        break;
    case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
    case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
    default:
        break;
    };
}

int main()
{
    /* 
    ------------------ START Initialize Server ------------------
     */

    int serverfd, clientfd;
    struct sockaddr_in vir_serv_addr, cli_addr;

    serverfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero((char *) &vir_serv_addr, sizeof (vir_serv_addr));

    vir_serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    vir_serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    vir_serv_addr.sin_port = htons(9999);

    bind(serverfd, (struct sockaddr *) &vir_serv_addr, sizeof (vir_serv_addr));
    listen(serverfd, 5);
    socklen_t client = sizeof (cli_addr);
    clientfd = accept(serverfd, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr, (socklen_t*) & client);

    /*
    ------------------- END Initialize Server ------------------- 
     */

    /* 
    ------------------ START SSL ------------------
     */
    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    SSL_CTX* context = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_server_method());
    SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(context, 1);
    SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(context, "server-cert.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(context, "server-key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(context, "ca-cert.pem", NULL);
    SSL_CTX_check_private_key(context);

    SSL* ssl = SSL_new(context);
    BIO *rbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO *wbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    SSL_set_bio(ssl, rbio, wbio);

    char* buffer[8192];
    int n;

    SSL_set_accept_state(ssl);

    while (!SSL_is_init_finished(ssl)) {
        n = recv(clientfd, buffer, 8192, 0);
        n = BIO_write(rbio, buffer, n);
        int r = SSL_do_handshake(ssl);
        n = BIO_read(wbio, buffer, 8192);
        n = send(clientfd, buffer, n, 0);

        bzero(buffer, 8192);
        BIO_flush(rbio);
        BIO_flush(wbio);

        if (r != 1) {
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            int err_SSL_get_error = SSL_get_error(ssl, r);
            switch (err_SSL_get_error) {
            case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
            case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
                return 0;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                continue;
            default:
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    string message = "Hello world! \n Bye world!";
    n = SSL_write(ssl, message.c_str(), message.size());
    n = BIO_read(wbio, buffer, 8192);
    n = send(clientfd, buffer, n, 0);

    /*
    ------------------- END SSL ------------------- 
     */

}
```

Comment: How did you check that the message is sent in 2 records? Because I doubt this. Maybe you tried to read it line by line?

Comment: Why does it matter how many SSL records the data is sent with?  The data is arbitrary. TCP will ensure it is sent reliably one way or the other, and the receiver's SSL engine will piece it back together in a coherent manner. SSL is free to send application data using however many records it wants.  Besides, even if SSL does not split the data, TCP still can.  Your requirement is not realistic.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: I used wireshark. In TLSv1.1 & TLSv1.2 it is just a SSL record but in TLSv1 it is 2 record and I must use this version of TLS.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Actually this code is simplified of a bigger project for being Database Proxy. In main project we need send a message to a server that is not under our control and it can only process 1 SSL record.

Comment: @Heil_Me But why? That is a faulty implementation on the server's part. Your proxy should not cater to such a bug. AFAIK, you can't force OpenSSL to act the way you are asking for. Get the server fixed instead. Or stop sending so so much data at one time that OpenSSL has to split it into multiple records.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I also send a space message like " ", but it split in 2 record!

Comment: @Heil_Me I **highly doubt** OpenSSL is parsing arbitrary application data to blindly decide to split the data on *textual whitespace*, like you claim. That would not make sense for OpenSSL to do that, considering the performance overhead in performing such scans, and the fact that OpenSSL doesn't know about application protocols to begin with. Something else has to be going on that you are not taking into account.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: no, it does not parse it. It does not matter what you put into the string but with the code it will create two application data TLS records (type 0x17). It is also not related to underlying TCP layer since the code uses memory BIO to construct the messages. And the one SSL_write will cause a buffer with two SSL records inside. And it happens only with TLS 1.0. Very strange indeed.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich even if OpenSSL is doing what you claim, it cannot be doing it for the reason you claim. Something else is going on. I suggest you either 1) debug into OpenSSL's source code (it is open-source, after all) and see exactly what it is doing and why, or else 2) ask the [OpenSSL support community](https://www.openssl.org/community/), where experts are much more likely to be able to help you understand the behavior.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I've found it. Its a feature not a bug. See answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very interesting question indeed. What happens here is that a single `SSL_write` results in two Application Data SSL frames (type 0x17). And this happens only with TLS 1.0, i.e. not with TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2.

While it might look like a bug it is actually done on purpose to fight the [BEAST](https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2013/09/10/is-beast-still-a-threat) and similar attacks which use a protocol vulnerability in SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0 in connection with CBC ciphers. This protection is done by inserting empty data fragments which leads to the first SSL frame which effectively contains no real data. Similar protections like this 0/n split exist in other TLS stacks in the form of 1/n-1 splits.

Since this attack does not affect TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 the protection is not enabled there. For more details about how this protection works see [Why does Firefox split HTTPS request?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63215/why-does-firefox-split-https-request) and [Is BEAST really fixed in all modern browsers?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18505/is-beast-really-fixed-in-all-modern-browsers/18535#18535).

But since you are burdened with some buggy application which cannot deal with this behavior you need to find a way to disable it. This can be done by choosing a cipher which is not CBC (but there are no good ones left in TLS 1.0) or by simply disabling the protection:

```
SSL_CTX_set_options(context, SSL_OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS);
```

Instead of `SSL_OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS` you could also use `SSL_OP_ALL` which includes all workaround for buggy TLS implementations including this one.